# 'System' : a namespace with this name does not exist

Tags: c++, wpf, build-error

I had a C++ project which was running perfectly. Now I copied the project to another folder and added the project to a WPF application solution.

Now the C++ project is giving me lot of build errors. One of them is `"System' : a namespace with this name does not exist"`.

Below are the lines which creates this error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;
using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace System::Security::Permissions;
```

The above lines are in **AssemblyInfo.cpp** file. I don't have any experience of C++, so finding it difficult to remove the errors. Any help is appreciated. Below is another error which might be helpful for you to resolve the issue.

```
managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you intend to write in C++ for .NET or natively? Existence of `System::*` shows clearly, that its a C++/CLI project (not C++/Win32).

Comment: Actually C++ is has some native code and wrapper and WPF does the UI. I know it is C++/CLI project. But why is it giving errors when added to another solution as this does not depend upon any other project.

Comment: Check in project's preferences, whether the compiler knows, that it's a C++/CLI project, because it seems, that it doesn't :)

Comment: @Spook: Can you please tell how to check this?

Comment: Project properties | Configuration properties | General | Common Language Runtime Support. If the project is a C++/CLI one, there should be `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)`.

Comment: Thanks Spook, it let me end my day with success.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Set Common Language RunTime Support to be "Common Language RunTime Support (/clr)" in **2** places in your project properties :

For Visual Studio before 2019:

- Configuration Properties -> General
- Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General

For Visual Studio 2019:

- Configuration Properties -> Advanced -> C++/CLI Properties
- Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General

Comment: Had the same issue and this worked for me, should be marked as the answer,

Comment: This worked for me on Visual Studio 2015, but I only changed the property in C/C++ -> General. I didn't see the property in just General.

Comment: For Visual Studio 2019,  go to the Configuration Properties -> Advanced -> C++/CLI Properties and do it.

Comment: What about projects that are made without Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Mif's answer was a little incomplete for me. If you still have the issue, you'd might want to check if you set the correct `C++`-version.
For me it specifically needed `ISO C++17` because the VS default preset `ISO C++14` (at least a preset in my version) does not support the required CLI-packages. Thus, still set the Runtime support to *Common Language RunTime Support (/clr)* and set the correct *C++ Language Standard* in the *Configuration Properties* -> *General* tab.

Note: As of now (October 2021) `ISO C++20` is currently not supported in CLI and will also fail to find `System` - I only found the 17-version to be compatible.

Since its a little easer the visual way, here the screenshots. And also don't forget Yinon_90's hint to have the version as well as dependencies installed!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was not enough for me when I just changed "Common Language RunTime Support (/ clr)".

I had to create the project in VS which would be a dedicated project for CLR:
[image]

If you cannot see this option, you should add it in the VS installer first:
[image]