# CLR namespace does not exist

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C# project with 2 function

```
namespace LibiqCommonStructures 
{
  public class BlackLevelData : List<BlackLevelLookupTable>
  {
      public BlackLevelData()
      {
      }

       public BlackLevelData(BlackLevelData original)
          : base(original.DeepCopy())
      {
      }

       public void AddLookupTable(double gain, double exposure, double[] levels)
      {
          var table = new BlackLevelLookupTable
          {
              AnalogGain = gain,
              ExposureTime = exposure,
             ChannelLevels = levels
          };

          Add(table);
      }
  }
}
```

same for SaturationLevelData

I created a c++\CLI project and I want to give the two class into a function as parameters

```
#pragma once
#include "Preprocessor.h"


using namespace LibiqCommonStructures;

namespace ToolBox {

    public ref class PreprocessorWrapper
    {
    public:        
        PreprocessorWrapper();        
        void Function1(BlackLevelData^ blackLevelData, SaturationLevelData^ saturationLevelData);
    private:
        Preprocessor* _preprocessor;
    };
}
```

header

```
 #include "PreprocessorWrapper.h"


void ToolBox::PreprocessorWrapper::Function1(BlackLevelData^ blackLevelData, SaturationLevelData^ saturationLevelData)
{    
    _preprocessor->Function1();
}

ToolBox::PreprocessorWrapper::PreprocessorWrapper()
{
    _preprocessor = new Preprocessor();
}
```

here are the errors I get

```
Error   2   error C2871: 'LibiqCommonStructures' : a namespace with this name does not exist    g:\iqtool2\src\libiqtool\preprocessor_interop\PreprocessorWrapper.h 5   1   Preprocessor_interop
Error   8   error C2448: 'ToolBox::PreprocessorWrapper::Function1' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition G:\IQTool2\src\libiqtool\Preprocessor_interop\PreprocessorWrapper.cpp   5   1   Preprocessor_interop
Error   6   error C2065: 'SaturationLevelData' : undeclared identifier  G:\IQTool2\src\libiqtool\Preprocessor_interop\PreprocessorWrapper.cpp   4   1   Preprocessor_interop
Error   7   error C2065: 'saturationLevelData' : undeclared identifier  G:\IQTool2\src\libiqtool\Preprocessor_interop\PreprocessorWrapper.cpp   4   1   Preprocessor_interop
Error   4   error C2065: 'BlackLevelData' : undeclared identifier   G:\IQTool2\src\libiqtool\Preprocessor_interop\PreprocessorWrapper.cpp   4   1   Preprocessor_interop
Error   5   error C2065: 'blackLevelData' : undeclared identifier   G:\IQTool2\src\libiqtool\Preprocessor_interop\PreprocessorWrapper.cpp   4   1   Preprocessor_interop
Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BlackLevelData' g:\iqtool2\src\libiqtool\preprocessor_interop\PreprocessorWrapper.h 13  1   Preprocessor_interop
```

Can you see what I did wrong here?

yes I have added the C# project as reference 
[image]

Comment: In your C++/CLI project, have you added a reference to the project/assembly that contains `LibiqCommonStructures`?

Comment: Did you add the C# dll as a reference?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko yes I did

Comment: Check if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732789/system-a-namespace-with-this-name-does-not-exist

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko no i did those two as well

Comment: Two things out of whack.  Very strange that the C++/CLI project doesn't reference any .NET assemblies.  And we cannot see Error #1, an error that could certainly explain all the other errors.  Like a "file not found" error for the C# assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you are building your C++ project with the /clr switch. It is strange you are not referencing at least the System assembly.

Second, the screenshot you provided seems to indicate that your C++/CLI project is using the .NET Framework v4.0. Assuming your C# project is using the .NET Framework v4.5, try updating your C++/CLI project to match. You can hand-edit the project file (.vcxproj) as follows:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I reproduced your issue by changing the version to v4.0 with Visual Studio 2013.