# Visual Studio 2017: namespace "System" has no member "Windows"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I recently installed the CLR package for Visual C++ and am making my first GUI. For some reason System is not showing all of the options that it has in the past. There are red lines under everything after System::* with similar errors.  Here is the start to my header file.

```
#pragma once


namespace Form1 {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

While searching for a solution I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732789/system-a-namespace-with-this-name-does-not-exist), and followed the steps

> Set Common Language RunTime Support to be "Common Language RunTime
>   Support (/clr)" in 2 places in your project properties :
>   Configuration Properties -> General
>   Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General

But that was already the default. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any header to include for such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add these references by :

Go to `Project` > `References` > `Common Properties` > `Framework and References`

Click `Add New References...` button

Under `Assemblies` -> `Frameworks` check `System`."`Your needs`" and click ok.