# How to include System in C++/WinRT console application

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

Using Visual Studio 2019 16.10.2 how do you include .NET components in a C++ / WinRT Console programme?

[The `indexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ivector-1.indexof?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Foundation_Collections_IVector_1_IndexOf__0_System_UInt32__) method [of `IVector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ivector-1?view=winrt-20348) requires  [a `UInt32` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint32?view=net-5.0) from `System`.

How is the `System` utilised in this context? Trying to use the namespace results in a

```
"System' : a namespace with this name does not exist"
```

[This has been covered already on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732789/system-a-namespace-with-this-name-does-not-exist), but only for a C++/CLI application and not in the context of a C++/WinRT console app. The solutions provided in that post also do not work.

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>

using winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector;
using namespace System;

int main()
{
    IVector<int> foo;
    foo.Append(1);
    UInt32 bar;
    foo.indexOf(1, bar);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In this case `pch.h` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select the appropriate language from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ivector-1.indexof?view=winrt-20348#Windows_Foundation_Collections_IVector_1_IndexOf__0_System_UInt32__)'s language dropdown list in the top right corner (C++/WinRT) you'll see the C++/WinRT-specific signature:

```cpp
bool IndexOf(T const& value, uint32_t & index);
```

You'll need to replace

```cpp
UInt32 bar;
```

with

```cpp
uint32_t bar{};
```

Comment: Lovely, incredibly obvious but I’ll let this question stand as it flummoxed a few developers.